# If statement to display Post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a taxonomy named `talent_cat` which is the category of said post, has 4 values: `modelos, atores, musica, djs` and inside each individual `talent_cat` there are these `post meta keys:`
`talent_id_1495127471815` for `modelos`
`talent_id_1495127471816` for `atores`
`talent_id_1495127471817` for `musica`
 `talent_id_1495127471818` for `djs`

How can I build a conditional to show the right `post meta` depending on the `talent_cat` of said post? So if the post belongs to `talent_cat = modelos` it returns the `talent_id_1495127471815` and not the other values.

I tried this but unsuccessfully:

```
$talent_data = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'talent_cat');
switch( $talent_data ) {
                case 'modelos':
                    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'talent_id_1495127471815', true);
                    break;
      }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get_the_term_list` returns HTML but you need to get an array or object to check your statement. You need to use `get_the_terms` function instead. Your code should look like this:

```
global $post;
$talent_data = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'talent_cat');

// check for errors or empty data
if ( is_wp_error( $talent_data ) || empty( $talent_data ) ) {
    return;
}

foreach ( $talent_data as $term ) {
    // you can check for name or slug or id
    switch( $term->slug ) {
        case 'modelos':
           echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'talent_id_1495127471815', true);
           break;
    }
}
```